# Can we bundle applet class as virtual app using Jwrapper

Tags: jwrapper

when I am trying to define my applet as Main class

```
<JWrapper>

    <!-- The name of the app bundle -->
    <BundleName>MemoryMap</BundleName>

    <!-- The specification for one app within the bundle -->
    <App>
      <Name>MemoryMap</Name>
      <LogoPNG>sampleapp/logo.png</LogoPNG>
     <MainClass>com.example.SampleApplet</MainClass>


    </App>
```

getting below exception
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.SampleApplet.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Not sure if we cannot define applet class as main class , does that mean Jwrapper could not bundle Applet?

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to specify an Applet or JApplet as the main class in a JWrapper application however converting an Applet or JApplet to a standalone class is usually a simple process of just creating a JFrame and embedding the applet UI into it, then specifying a main method to launch the JFrame.

Here's an example:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/337839/GUI/java/Convert-Applet-Stand-app

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I converted my Applet to standalone class and it worked well.

I read that JWrapper can be used as an Applet alternative , however when I bundled my app (Applet converted to standalone swing class) I saw an option to launch it as an offline /online exe i.e. as virtual app or as an Applet .

Wondering if we launch it as an Applet then how it would overcome Applet problems -- like reliance on an client System Jre , security settings etc..?

May be I am not getting how JWrapper is termed as an Applet alternative?